# Update Label control In first record of DataList during ItemDataBound

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label, datalist

Using Asp.net and VB.net.  I have a `DataList` on a webpage.  The datalist has a label control.  I want to update the text of the label control in the first record with information obtained from the subsequent records as those subsequent records are databound.  In other words, each time the datalist gets bound, I want to identify the label in the first record and then update the text of that label.  I'm attempting to do this in the `ItemDataBound` by getting the `ClientID` of the label in the first record:

```
   Dim strMealPrice As String = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblMealPrice"), Label).ClientID
```

and then hold that `ClientID` in a hidden label outside of the datalist.

```
 If lblhidMealHeaderID.Text = "" then
  lblhidMealHeaderID.Text = strMealPrice
 End if
```

Everything works up to this point.

Then each time the datalist `ItemDataBound` is fired I use findcontrol to try to update the label in the first record but I'm unsure how to format the findcontrol when using a variable for the label control's `ClientID` (`lblhidMealHeaderID.text`).  But even when I hard code the `ClientID` of the label in the first record I can't get it to work.

```
 Dim tempLabel As Label = DataList1.FindControl("DataList1_ctl00_lblMealPrice")
```

or

```
Dim tempLabel As Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("DataList1_ctl00_lblMealPrice"), Label)
```

I get a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when I try to write to tempLabel.

As you can see I'm grasping here.  First, is this the best way to do this - is the `ItemDataBound` where I should be attempting this?  Perhaps you can't update previous records while the `DataList` is "binding" subsequent records.   Second, is ClientID the way to do this - I see `ClientID` is used mostly for javascript?  Third, how do I properly format the FindControl using `ClientID`?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ItemDataBound` use this

```
If e.Item.ItemIndex = 0 Then
 CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblMealPrice"), Label).Text = strMealPrice
End If
```

**Update**

You can find the first label any time after binding by looping through its items.

```
For Each item as DataGridItem In dgGrid.Items
 CType(item.FindControl("lblMealPrice"), Label).Text = strMealPrice
Next
```

Comment: Bharadwaj - thanks for your response but I don't see how that will solve my problem.  That code sets the text of the label in the first record when it is binding that record (index = 0).  I need to write to that label when it is binding the other records (when index = 1 or 2 or 3, etc)

Comment: @user1375002 I have updated my answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks again.  That looks like it would work.  I actually ended up using a work around by using a separate data connection to the database during the itemdatabound event.